# Vectorized syntax for creating a sequence of block matrices in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 3D arrays `A` and `B` with shapes `(k, n, n)` and `(k, m, m)` respectively.  I would like to create a matrix `C` of shape `(k, n+m, n+m)` such that for each `0 <= i < k`,  the 2D matrix `C[i,:,:]` is the block diagonal matrix obtained by putting `A[i, :, :]` at the upper left `n x n` part and `B[i, :, :]` at the lower right `m x m` part.

Currently I am using the following to achieve this is NumPy:

```
C = np.empty((k, n+m, n+m))
for i in range(k):
    C[i, ...] = np.block([[A[i,...], np.zeros((n,m))],
                          [np.zeros((m,n)), B[i,...]]])
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without the `for` loop.  I think if `k` is large my solution is not very efficient.

Comment: Check the parenthesis completion again? Also, shouldn't B be lower-right?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the note.  Yes lower right is correct. Parenthesis look fine.

Comment: Well I wasn't able to run those because of one extra parenthesis and `np.zeros` call complained too. Feel free to edit back if you feel like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC You can simply slice and assign -

```
C = np.zeros((k, n+m, n+m),dtype=np.result_type(A,B))
C[:,:n,:n] = A
C[:,n:,n:] = B
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!